# Failed to display results Sequentially from BeanClass in Android?

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

i am getting data from database and putting it in Imageview now i am getting two id from DB i.e. 2 and 3  first it will set image of id 2 in imageview which is working fine and then next step is it will get questions related to that id from another function while its not doing its first extracting id 2 and id 3 then calling function for id = 3 but i snt want this...How can i overcome on this problem ? 
**CODE**

```
TableLayout questionHeadingTableLayout;
questionHeadingTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.questions_table);
   for(int i=0;i<topicBeanList.size();i++)
        {
        final TableRow questionHeadingTableRow = (TableRow) inflator.inflate(
                    R.layout.questions_table_row, null);
        LinearLayout questionHeadingLayout = (LinearLayout)questionHeadingTableRow.findViewById(R.id.question_heading_layout);  
        LinearLayout questionsLayout = (LinearLayout)questionHeadingTableRow.findViewById(R.id.question_layout);
        TopicBean topicBean = topicBeanList.get(i);
            Log.i("GetSubtopicsForTopic","");
            Log.i("getTopicImageName",""+topicBean.getTopicImageName());
            Log.i("getTopicId",""+topicBean.getTopicId());
            questionHeadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            questionsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ImageView questionHeadingImage = (ImageView)questionHeadingTableRow.findViewById(R.id.question_heading_imageview);
            questionHeadingImage.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset(topicBean.getTopicImageName()));
            ArrayList<QuestionBean> questionBeanList = AndroidUtil.externalDb.GetQuestions(topicBeanList.get(i).getTopicId());
            Log.i("questionBeanList size",""+questionBeanList.size());
    questionHeadingTableLayout.addView(questionHeadingTableRow);
        }
```

here is the xml:

```
    <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/questions_rowlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"
        >
         <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            > 

   <LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/question_heading_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/question_heading_imageview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
       android:clickable="false"
       android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/> 
     </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/question_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone"


    >
    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/questiontable_tablelayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/question_heading_layout"

        ></TableLayout>
     </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout> 
 </ScrollView>
</TableRow>
```

**METHOD:**

```
public ArrayList<QuestionBean> GetQuestions(int id)
{
    ArrayList<QuestionBean> questionBeanList = new ArrayList<QuestionBean>();
    String questionQuery = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE topic_id="+id+"";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(questionQuery, null);
     Log.i("Cursor questionQuery Print:",""+questionQuery);
      if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Log.d("cursor",""+cursor);
            QuestionBean questionBean = new QuestionBean();
            questionBean.setQuestionId(cursor.getInt(0));
            questionBean.setQuestionTopicId(cursor.getInt(1));
            questionBean.setQuestionImageName(cursor.getString(2));

            Log.i("cursor QuestionId",""+cursor.getInt(0));
            Log.i("cursor QuestionTopicId",""+cursor.getInt(1));
            Log.i("cursor QuestionImageName",""+cursor.getString(2));
            questionBeanList.add(questionBean);
            cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("", "Cursor is Null");
                Log.d("retrieving all parameters", "count < 0");
            }

            cursor.close();
            return questionBeanList;

}
```

Comment: plz explain more on this and properly format your code and your question first.

Comment: please see this LOC ImageView questionHeadingImage = (ImageView)questionHeadingTableRow.findViewById(R.id.question_heading_imageview);
            questionHeadingImage.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset(topicBean.getTopicImageName()));
            ArrayList<QuestionBean> questionBeanList = AndroidUtil.externalDb.GetQuestions(topicBeanList.get(i).getTopicId());

Comment: i am getting id = 2 and 3  from first loop then i want to call function  for id =2  ArrayList<QuestionBean> questionBeanList = AndroidUtil.externalDb.GetQuestions(topicBeanList.get(i).getTopicId())  but this function is first called for id=3;   why its happening

Comment: @MD is it clear now ?

Comment: i think you want to clear topicBeanList after called and before called.

Comment: no  ............. i have one question heading then all questions related to that heading will be displayed for that reason i want to get id of questionHeading and then retrieve questions for that heading

Comment: Your database Implementation AndroidUtil.externalDb.GetQuestions(...) available on this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48160/discussion-between-user3233280-and-m-d)