# Failed to get Columns Result From DB using 'like' in sqlite3 android?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-like

Here is my query that i am running but its returning me nothing even data exists in column i am trying to pass keywords mention by user and searching data in DB and providing result to the user.

My query is:

```
SELECT fatwa.question_id, question.ques_img_name 
FROM fatwa, question  
WHEREfatwa.fatwa_keywords LIKE "hadees" AND fatwa.question_id =question.id
```

While here is my Database: 
[image: table image]

Comment: try this `LIKE '%hadees%' in your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute your Query like:

```
SELECT fatwa.question_id, question.ques_img_name 
FROM fatwa, question  
WHERE fatwa.fatwa_keywords LIKE '%hadees%' AND fatwa.question_id =question.id
```

More information go to: [sqlite_like_clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm)

Comment: can someone please respond me here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958529/failed-to-display-results-sequentially-from-beanclass-in-android

Comment: actually i am getting id 2 and 3 from first function now i want to call 2nd function for id "2" then do somework for inside for loop and then then call 2nd function for id 3

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to the following:

```
SELECT fatwa.question_id, question.ques_img_name 
FROM fatwa, question  
WHERE fatwa.fatwa_keywords LIKE '%hadees%' AND fatwa.question_id =question.id
```

you are not using like command properly.

Comment: @RK check your query plz.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo Sorry wrote them in a hurry from a personal example. Editing now.

Comment: @RohanKandwal  can u pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958529/failed-to-display-results-sequentially-from-beanclass-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Use single quote with like statement:

```
SELECT fatwa.question_id, question.ques_img_name 
FROM fatwa, question  
WHERE fatwa.fatwa_keywords LIKE '%hadees%' AND fatwa.question_id =question.id
```

`question_id` should be an integer.

Comment: can u pls see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958852/failed-to-get-columns-result-from-db-using-like-in-sqlite3-android/21959107?noredirect=1#21959107

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958529/failed-to-display-results-sequentially-from-beanclass-in-android